# How does fixed parallelism strategy works in Junit5?

Tags: java, maven, junit5, junit-jupiter, parallel-testing

```
dynamic
Computes the desired parallelism based on the number of available processors/cores multiplied by the junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.dynamic.factor configuration parameter (defaults to 1).
```

Here, if the factor is not defined and my machine has 8 cores, 8 tests will run in parallel. And if I define the factor's value as 2, it means 16 tests will run in parallel on the 8 cores being present. So basically different threads will be used to run 16 tests on the 8 cores. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

```
fixed
Uses the mandatory junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism configuration parameter as the desired parallelism. The optional junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.max-pool-size configuration parameter can be used to limit the maximum number of threads.
```

Can someone explain the difference between junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism and junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.max-pool-size?

What is the relation of these properties in context to the cores present in the machines and the threads with respect to parallel test execution?

I tried fixed.parallelism=1 and fixed.max-pool-size=2, expecting that 2 methods will run in parallel but I noticed the sequential execution.

Comment: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution